# Visualization API LIne Chart and jQuery Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, charts, tabs, google-visualization

I have built some visualization tables and charts on a page and I have found an issue that I can't resolve.

I have separated tables & charts into categories using jQuery Tabs()

On one tab (Tab 4) I have a Pie Chart and a Line Chart

When the page loads and draws all the tables/charts and Tab 4 is NOT in focus (default) - the Line Chart does not draw the Legend OR Chart Labels. (the Pie Chart Loads fine)

[image]

When Tab 4 is in focus on page load - the Line Chart draws the Legend and Labels as expected.

How? Why?
Why would labels and legend not load if the Line Chart is within a div not initially visible?
Why do they load fine on the Pie Chart in the same situation?

Comment: this happens because the chart's container is hidden when it is drawn, as a result, the chart cannot properly calculate size and placement. wait until the tab is activated, before drawing for the first time...

Comment: Yes, I have deduced that based on my question. Why does pie chart draw properly? Why is it only the line chart?

Comment: it depends on the chart and the options used to draw it, would need to see the code, but if you wait until visible, should be fine...

Comment: thry this Plugin for googlechart using google vizualization data, https://github.com/cosmoarunn/gapiExt